# How did Eric survive after being burnt in the finale of season 6?

Tags: true-blood

In the season 6 finale of *True Blood*, we see Eric lose his immunity to the sun while on a mountaintop. He is shown burning with nowhere to run.

In season 7, he turns up with Hep-V.

What happened in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[He tells Sookie what happened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68205/how-did-a-certain-character-survive-post-season-6-finale-spoilers) in the fourth episode of season seven (S07E04, "Death Is Not the End"):

> “First I went home to Sweden, which was beautiful. But unfortunately,
>  I triggered an avalanche that killed an entire ski village. Things got
>  a little hectic after that.”

From there it is simple to deduce that he saved himself

> by diving in to the snow, which caused said avalanche.

Comment: Please edit your answer to read 'deduce' instead of deduct.